# Solving equation of xor and mod operation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, xor

How do I solve equations like this
$$(aX  \oplus X+b) \bmod M = c$$

If a,b and c are known?
and if i have system of of equation with different b values, is it solvable? I am particularly interested in $M$ being a power of $2.$

Comment: It's easy if $M$ is a power of 2.  I assume it's not...

Comment: lets say m = 2**128

Answer (score 2):

> is it solvable?

If $M$ is a power of 2, say, $2^{128}$, then it is easily solvable.

We first recognize that, in this system, what happens to bits $0-k$ are not affected by any of the bits $k+1$ and above.  That is, we can solve the system to the modulus $2^k$ and then extend that answer to higher order bits.

To be more concrete, here is what we can do:

- Define the set of the solutions modulo $2^0$; this set consists of a single entry $X = 0$, because for any integers $x, y$, $x \equiv y \pmod 1$
- For $k=1$ up to $128$ we consider the set of solutions modulo $2^{k-1}$
- For each such solution, we extend $X$ by setting bit $k-1$ to 0, and see if that's a solution.  If it is, we add that to the set of solutions modulo $2^k$.
- Then, we extend $X$ by setting bit $k-1$ to 1, and see if that's a solution.  If it is, we add that to the set of solutions modulo $2^k$

After we reached $k=128$, the final set will have all the solutions modulo $2^{128}$

And, yes, this process is fast

Comment: Yes. That tends to be applicable to solve for $X$ many equations $f(X)=0$ where $f$ has no right-diffusion (and $f$ does not collide too much, especially if we want all the solutions). Here, depending on how we read the question, $f(X)=((((aX)\oplus X)+b)\bmod2^b)\oplus c$, or $f(X)=(((aX)\oplus(X+b))\bmod2^b)\oplus c$  (with $b=128$).